# TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 3314:

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день возникла данная ошибка после ввода данных в поле на странице регистрации, вот ошибка https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUl5T.png ,  а вот сам код https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdwAj.png буду благодарен вашей помощи в решении данной проблем) Сайт на laravel, версия 5.3.30  Сайт был на сервере, теперь моя задача восстановить работу хотя бы на локальном сервере, мое мнение проблеме в .env

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` и `php artisan key:generate` пробовали?

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо вам большое ошибка ушла!

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена, я изменил УРЛЫ в файле .env, где к APP_URL добавил http://localhost и к SESSION_DOMAIN подставил localhost, далее я очистил кэш php artisan config:cache и сделал ключ php artisan key:generate, далее запустил проект php artisan serve